# Make multiple oblique-lined images in horizontal div clickable

Tags: html, css

not really sure if the title is well formed for my question, but it was the best i could do :)

I'm trying to create a horizontal bar with with multiple images, where all of them are oblique against the next one.. (see this image).

[image]

I'm not even sure if it's possible with CSS.. (and even though if it's possible when it scales up and down..)..

I want each picture in this horizontal bar clickable.. AKA : If you hover the samurai, an :hover effect applies and it's clickable (a href: )..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```css
body {
  margin:0
}

.cont {
  width:80%;
  height: 70%;
  display:flex;
  perspective:1000px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  display:flex;
}

.cont a {
  display:block;
  height: 100%;
  flex:1;
  background-size:cover;
  transform: skew(25deg);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cont a::before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -50%;
  right: -50%;
  transform: skew(-25deg);
   background-size:cover;
   background: url("https://picsum.photos/600/700");
   position: absolute;
}

.cont a:nth-child(2)::before {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/600/740");
}

.cont a:nth-child(3)::before  {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/600/720");
}

.cont a:nth-child(4)::before   {
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/600/750");
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Answers which explain how code works are downvoted less often than those which simply spoonfeed code to users...

Comment: the image are distored ...

Comment: you have applied skew to them, so they are skewed/distorted .. in the quetion the image are fine

Comment: I understand the thing though, but yea.. 

And.. @TemaniAfif got a point.. how do i do this without getting the images distorted ? Aka : cutting parts of the images instead of rotating them..

Comment: @TerjeNygård check the duplicate question

Comment: I will @TemaniAfif :) Thanks for contributing!.. much appreciated..

Comment: I can explain why i didn't find this duplicate : As i already mention in the post, i had issues with explaining _exactly_ what i was after (might be that i'm norwegian :))... 

If i had known what to search for more thoroughly.. i would have found this..  :)